# Macro , VBA or just excel in linking sheets but with a diffrent scenario

Tags: excel, vba

I want to link two excel sheets but here the scenario is a bit complex I beleive. I have a report template in excel (which runs with a macro to generate a reprt template). My job is to do analysis and fill in the values of the analysis in that excel report. Currently I do it manually but we are thinking to automate the process so that the values will automatically fill in the excel sheet.
I am thinking of linking the report sheet with analysis sheet(s) to do that. Is that correct? Also do I require a macro / VBA for that bacause everytime on running a different analysis, I will have a different analysis sheet to fill in the report sheet. 
I need this really urgent and would highly appreciate your time and suggestions.

Comment: Hi! I understand this is unclear. Let me try to put this in a more descriptive way. I have two excel sheets (one with data , lets say sheet A and other with a report template). I want to create a program that will automatically enter the values from data sheet (which contains numbers) to report sheet in specific cells. I hope this is more precise and clear than the previous one.

Comment: Instead of a long, verbose description, why not give a visual example. Please put this in the body of your question, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two worksheets, one for presentation and another that holds the data?

Linking would be best if your report is always the same size.  If it's not you can create a blank report that is the biggest size you will ever need and pre-link it to your data sheet.  Then just paste your data over that sheet and run a macro to hide the unused portions of your presentation/report sheet.

You can also do it with a full-blown macro, which will give you more flexibility in the long run.

Here is a tutorial for you: http://excelvbatutor.com/vba_tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is great tutorial but I could not find the one which explains linking of two excel sheets. My report is always the same size with fixed cells for data. I just want something like linking of cell A in excelsheet 1 to cell B in excelsheet 2. With this I would visualize changing just the name of source and master file and linking would automatically be done. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Oh, okay.  Here's what you do:  open both spreadsheets and link the cells normally like you would in any other situation.  Then, just overwrite the data workbook with a new data workbook in the same location.  When you reopen the report workbook, it will update its data.

Comment: Thanks. This will work. The other question with linking cells is that my data sheet has separate columns for numbers and their associated percentages but my report sheet should have both number and percentages in the same cell (eg: 10 (45.67%)). Is that possible with linking cells? 
Basically I am trying to automate my manual process of entering values from data sheet to report sheet (even though it is just copying and pasting but takes a lot of time). Is linking the most efficient way of doing this or would you suggest anything else? I really appreciate your time in this. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Sure.  Just concatenate the values in your presentation cell by doing this:  = A1 & " " & A2